# Shared Preferences not working?

Tags: android

Actually i m trying to make a demo shopping cart using shared preferences but the data is not storing in the cart. I m using three books and add that to the cart but when i m clicking on go to cart in home page,the data stored in the cart gets deleted every time.Please help me to sort out the issue .There must be some minor mistake in Shared Preferences

```
Home
package com.example.rajatanurag.shoppingsites;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {
    SharedPreferences sp1;
    Button bh1;
    Intent i;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        bh1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bh1);
        sp1 = getSharedPreferences("SHOPPING", MODE_PRIVATE);


    }

    public void onClick2(View view) {
        if(sp1.getBoolean("isTrue",false))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this, MyCart.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
       else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this, Home.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }


    }





    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);


    }


    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.page1) {
            i = new Intent(Home.this, Book.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.page2) {
            i = new Intent(Home.this, Electronics.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }



}




Books

package com.example.rajatanurag.shoppingsites;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Book extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button b1;
   CheckBox cb1,cb2,cb3;
    TextView tv1,tv2,tv3,tv7,tv8,tv9;
     SharedPreferences sp1;
    ImageView iv1,iv2,iv3;
    String x,y,z;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_book);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
        cb1=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb1);
        cb2=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb2);
        cb3=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb3);
        tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv4);
        tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        tv3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv3);
        tv7=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv7);
        tv8=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv8);
        tv9=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv9);
        iv1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv1);
        iv2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv2);
        iv3=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv3);
        sp1=getSharedPreferences("SHOPPING",MODE_PRIVATE);


    }

    public void OnClick1(View view)
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp1.edit();
        //editor.putString("book1",tv1.getText().toString());
        editor.putBoolean("isTrue",true);
        if(cb1.isChecked()==true) {

            editor.putString("price1", tv1.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("name1",tv7.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();


        }

        if(cb2.isChecked()==true)
        {

            editor.putString("price2",tv2.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("name2",tv8.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();



        }


        if(cb3.isChecked()==true)
        {

            editor.putString("price3",tv3.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("name3",tv9.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();



        }


        Intent i1=new Intent(this,MyCart.class);
        i1.putExtra("cb1", cb1.isChecked());
        i1.putExtra("cb2", cb2.isChecked());
        i1.putExtra("cb3", cb3.isChecked());
        startActivity(i1);

        //   Intent i=new Intent(this,MyCart.class);
     //   startActivity(i);








    }


}


MyCart


package com.example.rajatanurag.shoppingsites;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyCart extends AppCompatActivity {
    SharedPreferences sp1;
   public  String price11,price21,price31,name11,name12,name13;
     TextView tv4,tv5,tv6,tv10,tv11,tv12,tv20;
        Button b2h,p2c;
    int add;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_cart);
        tv4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv4);
        tv5=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv5);
        tv10=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv10);
        tv11=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv11);
        tv12=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv12);
        tv6=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv6);
        tv20=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv20);
        b2h=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b2h);
        p2c=(Button)findViewById(R.id.p2c);
        sp1=getSharedPreferences("SHOPPING",MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sp1.edit();
            int x=0,y=0,z=0;
        Intent intent=getIntent();
           // if(Book.cb1.isChecked()==true){
            if(intent.getBooleanExtra("cb1",false)){
               price11 = sp1.getString("price1", "");
                 x=Integer.parseInt(price11);
                name11 = sp1.getString("name1", "");
                editor.commit();

                tv4.setText(price11);

                tv10.setText(name11);
        }
           // if(Book.cb2.isChecked()==true){
        if(intent.getBooleanExtra("cb2",false)){
                 price21=sp1.getString("price2","");
                y=Integer.parseInt(price21);
                 name12 = sp1.getString("name2", "");
            editor.commit();

                tv5.setText(price21);
                tv11.setText(name12);
        }
               // if(Book.cb3.isChecked()==true){
        if(intent.getBooleanExtra("cb3",false)){
                 price31=sp1.getString("price3","");
                     z=Integer.parseInt(price31);
                    name13 = sp1.getString("name3", "");
            editor.commit();

                    tv6.setText(price31);
                    tv12.setText(name13);}
        add=x+y+z;

        //SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sp1.edit();
       // editor.commit();
    }

    public void BackToHome(View view)
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sp1.edit();
        sp1.getBoolean("isTrue",false);
        editor.commit();
        Intent i=new Intent(this,Home.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void Checkout(View view)

    {

        tv20.setText(Integer.toString(add));


    }



}``
```

Comment: Change `MODE_APPEND` to `MODE_PRIVATE`

Comment: No I used it but it's not working